# Disable Validation in Dojo datetextbox

Tags: dojo

Is there a way to turn off or disable client site validation in dojo's form widget datetextbox. I would like users to be able to type the date in if they want and support most common date formats

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear at "disable client site validation". If I understand you correct, you are asking to be able input any value manually and also be able to use date dropdown pickup.

There is an _isInvalidDate method you can try to overwrite like:

```
new DateTextBox({
        value: "31-DEC-2009",
        name: "oracle",
        _isInvalidDate: function(){return false;}
        onChange: function(v){ }
    }, "oracle");
```

Since this is an internal(private) method, it is not suggested but may work.

There is another method you can feel free to overwrite to use your own validation Regexp in constrints:

```
validator: function(/*anything*/ value, /*__Constraints*/ constraints){
```